# Won't Display More Than 999 Rows in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, css-grid

For some reason, in Chrome, elements begin overlapping one another once 999 rows have been printed. It works fine in Firefox. The version of Chrome that I'm using is `70.0.3538.102 (Official Build) (64-bit)`, which was just released earlier today.

The pages are sorted alphabetically, and I don't experience this issue on any other page because the 'A' page is the only page with more than 999 rows.

[image]

```
#data {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(8, max-content);
  grid-template-rows: auto;
}

<section id="data">
   ...
  <div>1000</div><div>axelle</div><div>G</div><div>92,296</div><div>2018-11-09</div><div>NULL</div><div>0</div><div>2018-11-09 07:49:36</div><div>1001</div><div>axes</div><div>G</div><div>88,536</div><div>2018-11-09</div><div>NULL</div><div>0</div><div>2018-11-09 07:49:36</div><div>1002</div><div>axethrowing</div><div>G</div><div>138,823</div><div>2018-11-09</div><div>NULL</div><div>0</div><div>2018-11-09 07:49:36</div><div>1003</div><div>axial</div><div>G</div><div>395,943</div><div>2018-11-09</div><div>NULL</div><div>0</div><div>2018-11-09 07:49:36</div><div>1004</div><div>axialracing</div><div>G</div><div>165,508</div><div>2018-11-09</div><div>NULL</div><div>0</div><div>2018-11-09 07:49:36</div><div>1005</div><div>axilas</div><div>G</div><div>87,736</div><div>2018-11-09</div><div>NULL</div><div>0</div><div>2018-11-09 07:49:36</div><div>1006</div><div>axiom</div><div>G</div><div>110,834</div><div>2018-11-09</div><div>NULL</div><div>0</div><div>2018-11-09 07:49:36</div><div>1007</div><div>axioo</div><div>G</div><div>321,874</div><div>2018-11-09</div><div>NULL</div><div>0</div><div>2018-11-09 07:49:36</div>
   ...
</section>
```

Is this a Chrome bug or?

Comment: Please show us the markup and CSS that you're using. (Are you actually using CSS Grid, not an HTML table?)

Comment: @duskwuff added, although i don't think it's an issue with the HTML/CSS since it works fine in firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS Grid specification makes explicit provisions for the handling of very large grids:

> Since memory is limited, UAs may clamp the possible size of the grid to be within a UA-defined limit, dropping all lines outside that limit. If a grid item is placed outside this limit, its grid area must be clamped to within this limited grid.

(https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#overlarge-grids)

The specification goes on to give an example involving a hypothetical UA with a grid size limit of 1000, implying that this is a typical limit.

This is not an appropriate application for CSS Grid functionality. Use an HTML table -- this is exactly the sort of thing they're made for.

Comment: ok thanks. not sure why Chrome would implement the limit, whereas it's all good in Firefox :/ what is UA?

Comment: @BugWhisperer UA stands for User Agent. It’s a string that tells the server some basic details about the client, such as “Safari on a Mac”, or a “Chrome on an Android device”. It helps to load specific webpage configuration, if any. For example, you could have a separate mobile-optimised navigation and layout, and use the UA string to verify the client, and load that version specifically.

Comment: ahhh i abbreviate it as 'uas'